# Login page issue with FormsAuthentication in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

I have a website that is using FormsAuthentication when a user is enters the site. The landing page is home.aspx. So when the user goes to www.mywebsite.com then get to the Login page.

For some reason, the user would enter userID and pwd then click the Login button, the page would submit, and the userID and pwd fields would empty out, and the login page would reappear (no message is displayed that userid or pwd is invalid).

When the user enters that information a 2nd time, they are able to enter the site.

Has anyone else experienced such a scenario? I need to avoid a user from having to enter their information twice in order to enter the site.

Comment: Are you doing some redirects before login? Check the `ReturnUrl` in the url, this behavior happens when the Login.aspx is in the `ReturnUrl`

Comment: A little bit more info would be good; e.g. is home.aspx the login page, or you have a separate one? Are username/password controls only on login page? Do you let FormsAuthentication do its default work related to redirection, and similar - or does your code redirect? What's the redirect flow (e.g. home.aspx is default page at IIS; the whole site except login.aspx is protected by forms-auth; forms-auth sends the user to login.aspx, etc).

Comment: @GustavoFreddo well, the landing page is home.aspx. So when the user types www.mywebpage.com I am guessing IIS goes www.mywebpage.com/home.aspx --> login.aspx --> home.aspx.... correct?

Comment: @Hari Home.aspx and login are two separate pages. Login.aspx has userid textbox, pwd textbox and login button. Not sure about the rest of your questions. I will get that info soon as I get to work.

Comment: by default, if you haven't changed forms-auth settings in web.config, if you protect the whole site (authorization > deny users="?"), then the only page allowed anon access is the one from forms-auth > login setting (login.aspx by default). Unless the user goes directly to login.aspx, you'll always have ReturnUrl in query when on that page. If in login-onclick on server you use FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage, you'll always go back where you came from (ReturnUrl). So, check if you're doing anything custom that would cause this flow to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a Visual Studio issue, i had exactly the same problem with my solution:

```
    protected void lkbSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text))
        {
```

putting a breakpoint on the `if` statement line stopped the strange behaviour from happening completely.

Also, when it was deployed to IIS and running as a proper website it didn't happen there either, despite using exactly the same source code.